# how make import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech works in google-cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to use google-cloud for speech to text conversion. After installing google-cloud,I get import error by this:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
```

import error:

```
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-26-aca8ce269e21>", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1p1beta1\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1p1beta1\types.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.proto import cloud_speech_pb2

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1p1beta1\proto\cloud_speech_pb2.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2

ImportError: No module named apiNo module named api
```

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback? Everything above `import error`.

Comment: Can you show how you installed the `google-cloud-speech` package?

Comment: I used: pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech

Comment: Can you include the output of `pip freeze`? What are the details of your system? How are you running the Python script with the import in it?

Comment: @Dustin Ingram, the output of    pip freeze is huge, can't paste it here. I am using python 2.7 and installing google-cloud in Anaconda prompt